# pgr_drivingdistance wrapper

Tags: postgis, sql, pgrouting

Pgr_drivingdistance function works as :

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, cost
    FROM pgr_drivingDistance(
            'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table',
            id, distance, false, false
    );
```

How could I get this to work substituting x, y for id?

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, cost
    FROM pgr_drivingDistance(
            'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table',
            x,y, distance, false, false
    );
```

Checking the pgrouting functions in Postgis I have found SQL code to change but not for pgr_drivingdistance.

Comment: I 'm sorry it took to answer. Thanks for your help.
I'll work under your recommendation.

Comment: I don't think you can pass x/y into the driving distance function. You would have to join the results back onto the original table to get the x and y.

Comment: I tried the following code:
`SELECT id,seq, id1 AS node,ST_X(the_geom) AS x, ST_Y(the_geom) AS y,id2 AS edge, cost, the_geom 
FROM pgr_drivingdistance('SELECT id, source, target, time_4 as cost FROM jaen',1493, 5, false, false)as di
JOIN jaen_vertices_pgr pt
ON di.id1 = pt.id;`and the result show x y fields for each node.Now i am trying to use `EXECUTE 'SELECT id::integer FROM jaen_vertices_pgr
ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText(''POINT('||x||'' ||y||')'',4326) LIMIT 1' INTO rec;
source := rec.id;` from pgr_fromatob function and change the pgr_dijkstra function to pgr_drivingdistance.

Comment: So, you are getting the x, y fields, you want? There was an error in original post, you need to join id1 against source, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The final objetive is to write sql code into geoserver id and pass the id as x y parameters so when an user click on map ( leaflet ) a polygon is drawn using pgr_pointsaspolygon. These points are generated from pgr_drivingdistance.I thing pgr_drivingdistance function is fairly accurate to calculating areas of influence.

Comment: Great. Please consider marking question as accepted, if this helped. And, feel free to ask another question for anything else.

Comment: Very well. Thank you very much and keep you informed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source declaration of [pgr_drivingDistance](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/driving_distance/sql/routing_dd.sql) you will see that it is linking to a C function, [driving_distance](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/driving_distance/src/drivedist.c). So unless you want to change the underlying C function, and recompile, you are stuck, as this is not one of those `plpgsql` functions that you can change directly, unlike say [pgr_pointsAsPolygon]((https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/driving_distance/sql/routing_dd.sql) from the same source, which you could change directly.

However, you can join the returned id on the original table, to return the x, y values easily enough.

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, edge.x, edge.y, cost
FROM pgr_drivingDistance(
        'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table',
        id, distance, false, false
) 
as dist
INNER JOIN 
edge_table edge on dist.id1 = edge.source;
```

Comment: Does this answer make sense? You're joining edge ID's with node ID's. Node ID's in your network table are either `source` or `target` ID's.

Comment: Well, you cannot assume that the `dist.id1` is `source`. It could be also `target` or it could be even both. I think your answer is still not correct. It would be better to use the vertices table, which you can create, if it doesn't exist yet: http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/functions/create_vert_table.html#pgr-create-vert-table

Comment: Hello.Finally i have used the next function that provide the id parameter from mark coordinates:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pgr_nearest_node(IN tbl character varying, IN x1 double precision, IN y1 double precision, OUT source integer,OUT geom Geometry)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
source integer;
BEGIN    
RETURN QUERY    
 -- Find nearest node
 SELECT id,the_geom FROM jaen_vertices_pgr 
  ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT( ' || x1 || ' ' || y1 ||' )',4326) LIMIT 1 ;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;`
Thank you very much for your help.